# WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Gson with qualifiers @Default

Tags: gson, cdi, weld

All my other Injections are working but it's not working with gson. I have the feeling it's because it's an external package, but I can't resolve the issue. Here are my relevant files:

Producer:

```
public class GsonFactory {
    @Produces
    public Gson createGson(){return new GsonBuilder().createGson();}
}
```

injectionpoint:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SoundcloudAPIWrapper implements Serializable{

    @Inject
    private Gson gson;

    public SoundcloudAPIWrapper() {}

    ...

}
```

Beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all" version="2.0">
</beans>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that `@Produces` is not `@javax.ws.rs.Produces`, but rather, `@javax.enterprise.inject.Produces`

Comment: So it works if you replace Gson with String?

Comment: thank you it was the enterprise `@javax.enterprise.inject.Produces` . now it's working. But why doesn't `@javax.ws.rs.Produces` work? All my other factories use the `ws.rs` . I'm very new to javaee, so an explanation would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like @maress pointed out in the comment, I needed to replace `@javax.ws.rs.Produces` with `@javax.enterprise.inject.Produces`. It's now working

Comment: I was stuck on these for days. And everything was in the import! You're a genius!